# Permissions issues when using python through PHP

Tags: php, python, permissions

I need to have my Python program open a file, use some of the data in it, and spit out a different file. I'm having several issues, and was hoping if someone could definitively tell me if they are permissions based and if so, how to fix them. My Python program works through the terminal.

Here are some areas I've identified where it doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
infile = open('/correct_pathway/textfile1.txt','r')
outfile = open('/correct_pathway/textfile2.txt','w')
```

It is having troubles on all of these separately. I didn't know there could be permissions issues while importing a module, but there are. Also the files are globally read/writable that it is trying to open.

EDIT: Sorry, that was unintentionally vague and had a typo in the code that was not actually there. The PHP code as written on the webpage is as follows (it works if I call in a much simpler python program, so there is no problem I can think of here):

```
<?php  $command= '/usr/bin/python /correct_pathway/program.py';
$temp = exec($command, $output);
print_r($temp); ?>
```

The code is supposed to open the infile, read a number off of it, and then write that number to the outfile as well as print off a different number. The printed number should be displayed on the webpage. This all works fine through the terminal, just not on the webpage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are running this through php (as in exec?)

Comment: How is php involved at all here? And is this code *supposed* to work? because it's clearly using unbound variables!

Comment: I suspect a typo, but you're missing a quote mark and semi-colon at the end of your PHP line defining `$command`.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typos, does this seem to anyone else like a permissions problem? I don't have direct access to the python modules to change them myself but can tell the tech people to do it for me if that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it could be a permissions problem:  Is the Python program runnable by the PHP process?  Does the PHP process have permission to write the Python program's output file?  Note that some of this may be influenced by the permissions given the web server software and also PHP, not just the file permissions.

Comment: Regarding typos in the example: the `$command` definition line in the code you present is still missing a quote mark ...

Comment: Sorry, fixed that typo too. The Python program is runnable by the PHP process, I've checked by commenting out everything except a simple print statement. The PHP process does not seem to have the permission to write the program's output file, though I don't know how to check it (is there a way?). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To define how a file should be opened, i.e. read or write, the syntax is to surround the r or w with quotes. So your above code should look like the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
infile = open('/correct_pathway/textfile1.txt','r')
outfile = open('/correct_pathway/textfile2.txt','w')
```

see if you can access the files with the quotes added.